# How could I ship SSL certificate update to a running app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

My company has got a software that is used on-premise and installed as a Windows service. We are adding now a WebAPI to it using .NET core 2.1. This API should be secured with SSL and if we buy a certificate it will last at most two years. Is there any way of automatically updating the certificate used for HTTPS? Some customers buy the software and don't upgrade as often as we would like. How could we ship a new certificate for them?

Update 07/03:
Our on-premise solution has been working at the backend as a service for 6 years (with two major updates per year). Now we are integrating a webapi in this service. No IIS here, just a self hosted webapi. Our service could use our own SSL certificate but then we will need to replace it somehow when it expires.

Comment: Does https://medium.com/@MaartenSikkema/automatically-request-and-use-lets-encrypt-certificates-in-dotnet-core-9d0d152a59b5 help?

Comment: not completely clear what you're asking. Do you host Web Api on web server? How your clients suppose to upgrade it?

Comment: Can you please clarify if the software is the Web server or Web client? Why would you ship a certificate to customers? That would be their responsibility to configure the certificate in the server like any other website. I think someone in your office needs to become familiar with how HTTPS is deployed.

Comment: @Alexan As I said in my post I host it as a Windows Service. Our on-premise solution has been working at the backend as a service for 6 years (with two major updates per year). Now we are integrating a webapi in this service. No IIS here, just a self hosted webapi. I will add the information to my original question.

Answer (score 0):

> How could I ship SSL certificate update to a running app?

**You don't need to distribute the server certificate to client devices if it is signed by a CA they trust.**

Ideally the client systems should trust a Certificate Authority (CA) that has a very long validity period (e.g. 20 years). That CA then issues short-lived certs (e.g. 6-12 mo) to the webservers. The clients will trust these certificates because they are signed by the CA they trust.

This is how the public web works today. The CA's are companies with big insurance policies, like Verisign, and the OS or browser vendors determine whoch CA's make the cut and get included into the certificate bundles which they manage by their own mechanisms (e.g. automatic updates).

So an option is to simply **buy an HTTPS certificate from a public CA**.

You can also be your own CA, but then you need to manage protecting the highly-sensitive root CA keys, and the distribution of your CA cert to all of the client devices.

Comment: I think the question is about shipping certs to **servers** not **clients**.

Comment: @mjwills, what does it mean shipping to servers? certificate is for domain name.

Comment: @Alexan Yes. The server is the one serving up the content for the domain name.

Comment: @mjwills, yes I know. But how much servers they have? For each client?

Comment: The initial question states 'on premise' @Alexan so presumably that means 'for each client'.

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart: The servers with our backend will be installed on-premise and we don't administrate them. If the customer decides not to upgrade their servers the certificates will expire. For example the certificate for this site expires on 08/14/2019. Stackoverflow will replace it next year and everybody will be happy.

Comment: Right. Lots of on-premises software requires the administrators to manage the certs. If your clients need you to babysit their installations, I would charge more for your services.